# Is there a way to source control an entire database, not just scripts that I choose to save to my git enabled folder?

Tags: azure-data-studio

Using Azure Data Studio, is there a way or extension that allows me to mark a database as being under source control, and upon doing so, have it automatically add my changes to source control.

Instead it seems I have to save each alter statement to the folder that is git enabled.

If there is a free extension that works under Azure Data Studio that does this, that would be great. I know there are many 3rd party commercial apps out there. Not looking for any of those.